# How can I check image orientation in Angular before uploading image

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I just want to image being upload on my website must portrait or square and I don't want to crop image, image to be uploaded must be portrait or square by default I have searched number of website \ number method use but none worked

know I am trying this method but it also not working because it is running async

if give landscape image in given code it runs if which should not run as
`hasError` must be true but doesn't because if condition run before the above code could complete so what can I do

```
 let hasError = false;
 image = event.target.files[0];
    if (image) {
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(image);
      img.onload = function () {
        height = img.naturalHeight;
        width = img.naturalWidth;
        console.log(hasError);  // prints false
        if (height < width)  {
           hasError = true; // prints true 
           console.log(hasError);
        }
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(img.src);
     }
    console.log(hasError); //prints flase
   }
   if(!hasError){
       .... 
   }
```

Comment: I believe the `img.onload` function has to be defined BEFORE you set `img.src`, try that.

Comment: Your problem is that you are trying to access the value of `hasError` before the image has finished loading.  `img.onload` is asynchronous, meaning the rest of your code will continue running and then when the image is loaded the onload function will **then** execute.  Your issue is nothing to do with image orientation, since you say that it is outputting `true` when the image is landscape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should create a function and move your image validation into your function and use a callback to find out the image has error or not.

```js
var fileInput = document.querySelector('input[type="file"]');
var preview = document.getElementById('preview'); //img tag

previewImage(function(hasError){
  if (!hasError){
    //do something
  }
});

function previewImage(callback){
  fileInput.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    preview.onload = function() {
      
        height = this.naturalHeight;
        width = this.naturalWidth;
        if (height < width)  {
           callback(true);
        } 
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(this.src);
        callback(false);
    };

    var url = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]);
    preview.setAttribute('src', url);
}, false);
}
```